# Unable to make cuts to audio and video track at the same time

Tags: premiere, premiere-pro

I have a video with audio that I imported in Premiere Pro. I was able to make cuts in the video track by pressing C and Premiere Pro would then automatically make cuts at the exact same location in the audio track.

I pressed some buttons that did something and I am no longer able to cut the video and audio at the same time. I searched on Google and links the tracks by going to Clip > Link does not help.

Once again I would like to mention that the audio and video are from the same file and not independent. I was able to make cuts in them or delete them at once earlier.

How can I start doing that again?

Thanks.

Comment: To link the clips together again you need to select the audio and the video segments by shift clicking both of them so that they are both selected, then press ctrl+L to link.  Did this help?

Comment: Thanks @tomh I probably figured out the issue. I clicked on the video track and made a cut by pressing the `Alt` key. The right part of the video track then got permanently unlinked. However, selecting the video track along with audio track and then pressing `Ctrl + L` didn't help me link them back.

Comment: Sometimes the way premiere links clips is a little bit unintuitive. e.g. you might have ended up with two audio clips and one video clip, with the wrong audio clip linked to the video clip, if that makes sense

Comment: @tomh So the only way for me to link them together is to just delete the cut I made with the`Alt` keypress?